# Jquery receiving a time value from input time and add one hour

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have this input:

```
{!! Form::time('horaini', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'required', 'id'=>'horaini']) !!}
```

And that:

```
{!! Form::time('horafim', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'required', 'id'=>'horafim']) !!}
```

So, i want when user put time on 'horaini' when his leave field, automatic 'horafim' set his time to 1 hour more .

i started with something like this:

```
$('#horaini').blur(function () {
// var valor = $('#horaini').val();
$('#horafim').val($('#horaini').val()+1);
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function to increase the value of the time input, you only need to receive the input id or you can modify it according to your needs:

```
function incrementTimeInput(id){
    var time = document.getElementById(id);  // Get time input
    var val = time.value;                       // Get input value
    time.stepUp(60);                 // Increment input 1 hour (60 min) 
    var inc = time.value;

    // check if is the last hour of the day 
    if (val == inc) {
        time.stepDown(60*23);
    }
}
```

Comment: its works, thanks so much, i had to do some changes because this function changes the input value entered, and I needed it to change from another input. But perfect, thank you.